# How to create a virtual field based on another hasMany table

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, virtual

This is a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413830/cakephp-how-to-create-virtual-field-based-off-another-table), but with a different relationship between the tables.

I have 3 tables: `users`, `notifications`, and `user_notifications`.  `user_notifications` is a join table between users and notifications, and represents an instance of a notification having been sent to a user.

The relations are as follows:

```
User => hasMany   => UserNotification
UserNotification => belong to => User, Notification  
Notification => hasMany => UserNotification
```

The columns are as follows:
    User => id, name
    UserNotification => id, user_id, notification_id
    Notification => id, message

I wanted to create a virtual field called `Notification.users` that simply held a string list of all the users that had been sent that particular notification, for example:

```
User => id = 1, name = Bob
User => id = 2, name = Bill

UserNotification => id = 1, user_id = 1, notification_id = 1
UserNotification => id = 2, user_id = 2, notification_id = 1

Notification => id = 1, message = "Hello World!"
```

So notification 1, "Hello World!" has been sent to users 1 and 2, Bob and Bill.  Therefore, the virtual field `Notification.users` contains a comma-separated list of those two names, and I see:

```
Notification => id = 1, message = "Hello World!", users = "Bob,Bill"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that ended up working for me is this:

```
class Notification extends AppModel
{
    public $virtualFields = array(
        "users" => "SELECT string_agg(users.name, ',') FROM users where users.id IN (SELECT user_notifications.user_id FROM user_notifications where user_notifications.notification_id = Notification.id)"
);
```

[`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) aggregates the selected columns into a string, using the optional delimiter provided.  One problem I ran into at first was the user of CakePHP aliases ("User", "UserNotification") for the other tables; this lead to "table not provided" errors, so I used the actual database table names.  By default, values are fed to `string_agg()` in no particular order, and this can lead to a somewhat jumbled string.  `string_agg()` supports an order by clause to solve this problem, as follows (note the lack of a comma between the delimiter, `','`, and the order by clause):

```
class Notification extends AppModel
{
    public $virtualFields = array(
        "users" => "SELECT string_agg(users.name, ',' ORDER BY users.name) FROM users where users.id IN (SELECT user_notifications.user_id FROM user_notifications where user_notifications.notification_id = Notification.id)"
);
```

This works and seems like the simplest solution to me.  Is there a more elegant or more correct one?